# How to stop multiple event handler onclick on html from servise resnonse?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-ui

I have on page div block:

```
<div class='btn'>click here</div>
<div class='dialogWindow'></div>
```

and js with click handler:

```
$('.btn').live('click', function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "services/service1.php"        
    }).done(function(result) {
        $('.dialogWindow').empty().append(result).dialog();
        // Handler for btn in HTML from service1
        $('.newBtn').live('click', function(){
            alert('click on new btn');
        });
    });
});
```

HTML from service1:

```
<div class='newBtn'>click here</div>
```

When user click on *div.btn* ajax return from *service1* HTML with new *div.newBtn*. New HTML displayed in jQuery dialog-window. When user close dialog-window and open it again by clicking on *div.btn* and after that clicking on div.newBtn => click-event on div.newBtn run two times.
How run click-event on div.newBtn only ones not dependency upon how many times user open jQuery dialog window?????

Comment: Try `event.stopImmediatePropagation?` inside `live` of `.newbtn`!

Comment: same result with 'stopImmediatePropagation'. Not working.

Comment: I am not sure in your scenario but `event.stopImmediatePropagation` works.. See this **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/kb7tpu29/)**

Comment: I make mistake to place it in correct place. Works :)

Comment: Great!! Happy coding.. :)

Comment: Don't use `live` use `on` as in `$('.btn').on('click', function(){`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is every time you click the btn you attach a new event handler to newBtn.

If you don't have any other event handlers on the button - your code can just remove existing click handlers before attaching new ones (sorta like this)

```
$('.btn').live('click', function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "services/service1.php"        
    }).done(function(result) {
        $('.dialogWindow').empty().append(result).dialog();
        // Handler for btn in HTML from service1
        $('.newBtn').die( "click" );
        $('.newBtn').live('click', function(){
            alert('click on new btn');
        });
    });
});
```

In addition I'm not sure what version of jquery you are developing for but .live has been deprecated for quite a long time. If possible I would switch to on/off

Answer (score 0):

Probably more efficient to attach the handler outside the event promise:

```
$('.dialogWindow').on('click','.newBtn', function(){
    alert('click on new btn');
});
$('.btn').on('click', function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "services/service1.php"        
    }).done(function(result) {
        $('.dialogWindow').empty().append(result).dialog();
    });
});
```